# How to check If a twitch streamer is live?

Tags: javascript, fetch, twitch-api

I was trying to check if a twitch streamer is live or not but when I tried it gave me a error.

here is my code:

```js
async function isStreamerLive(username) {
  const theUrl = `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login=${username}`
  const headers = {
    "Client-Id": 'ID', //hidden
    "Authorization": 'TOKEN', //hidden
  };

  const response = await fetch(theUrl, headers);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data)
  return data?.data?.find(s => s.user_login === username.toLocaleLowerCase())
}
let username = 'kaicenat'
isStreamerLive(username)
```

Output:

```
{
  error: 'Unauthorized',
  status: 401,
  message: 'OAuth token is missing'
}
```

Why is it saying OAuth token is missing?
I am also providing client id and token when I tried code.

Comment: Did you use the oauth2 route to create the token?

Comment: oauth2 means? I opened https://dev.twitch.tv/console and clicked on register new application and then added name and it asked for url then I added localhost

Comment: Start by reading this: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/get-started/. You'll need to create a token using the oatuh route

Comment: Ok I got the token but what is this bearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if its still relavent but you can check if a streamer is live by using

```
async function checkIfLive(username) 
{
    try 
    {
        const response = await fetch(`https://twitch.tv/${username}`);
        const sourceCode = await response.text();

        if (sourceCode.includes("isLiveBroadcast")) 
        {
            console.log(`${username} is live`);
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log(`${username} is not live`);
        }
    }
    catch (error) 
    {
        console.log("Error occurred:", error);
    }
  
}

let username = "kaicenat";
checkIfLive(username);
```

ill explain a bit more,
basically when a streamer is live "isLiveBroadcast" is in the source code of the twitch page, but when the user isn't live it isnt there.